# include внешнего файла html в html

Tags: html

Добрый день! Можно ли как то подключить внешнюю страницу html? 
Нашёл такое решение, но оно не работает

```
<!--#include file="content.html"-->
```

Может есть какая то альтернатива?

Comment: "подключить внешнюю страницу html" - объясните, что Вы под этим понимаете, и почему Вас не устраивает решение, которое у Вас уже есть.

Comment: html - это язык разметки. В нем нет функций, особенно include. Такой функционал присутствует в сборщиках html файлов. Так же можно использовать клиентские библиотеки http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для HTML альтернатива одна - [iframe](https://webref.ru/html/iframe)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/125167)

Comment: @cheops, с чего это имя тега стало ответом-ссылкой? o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy ответ очень короткий, именно, поэтому система идентифицировала его как низкокачественный. Вместо указания ссылки хорошо бы продемонстрировать работу с iframe на примере, который останется тут даже в том случае, если ресурс выше прекратит существование.

Comment: @cheops, тем не менее, это ответ. И не ссылка.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, ответ, только низкокачественный.

Answer (score 1):

> `<!--#include file="content.html"-->`

Это инструкция SSI (Server Side Include). Как настроить SSI для вашего веб-сервера - читайте в документации к этому серверу